# Programmatic login to Google Data API

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-data-api

I'm building an application which will basically be an interface for my Google Finance account. Several people will use. I have just started to research on how to do this, and one thing that immidiately seems like a hurdle is Google's oAuth system, seemingly designed for the case where each user logs into his account himself.

The usual proceeding as I understand it is that from my web application, the user gets redirected to Google's page, where they enter their information, and then are sent back. I will wind up with an authorized token that I can use to pull the data that I want.

BUT, now, as my application will ALWAYS and ONLY pull data from my account no matter who is logged in to my application, I need to always be authorized and it needs to happen programmatically without the user ever knowing.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is designed to be an interface to **YOUR** Google Finance account that **several people will use**, then OAuth is probably not the answer you're looking for.

OAuth would allow your app to pull information from your users' Google Accounts, whereas ClientLogin would allow your application to pull data from a single account.

Check the Google Finance API for more details and examples:

http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ClientLogin